# Sharepoint 2013 Branding with Visual studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, asp.net, branding, visual-studio-2015

I'm pretty new to C# and ASP.net and have a project to brand our internal SharePoint site. So I need a source book to learn Visual studio 2015 (C# and ASP.net) Does anyone knows about a book focusing on SharePoint branding by using ASP.net? or any other sources? i cannot find any. there are some books which use sharePoint Designer but no VS 2015.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to learn C# and Asp.net for branding.

For branding you will need to have knowledge of HTML and CSS.
You can get tons articles on Google for SharePoint 2013 branding .

For e.g. http://en.share-gate.com/blog/where-and-how-to-start-branding-sharepoint

C# and Asp.net comes in the picture when you want to develop custom solutions which are not possible in SharePoint out of box.

Answer (score 0):

Adding something to @**P S**. You can also check following youtube video by **Rackspace** for branding:

[Branding Internet Facing Web Sites with SharePoint 2013 (Full Session)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_d_izWMLCE)

> This session will focus on creating branded Internet-facing sites
>   using Public Websites in SharePoint Online but most of the techniques
>   will apply no matter where your SharePoint implementation lives!
>   Whether you're already taking advantage of Public Websites with Office
>   365, thinking about using them for your site, or just want to learn a
>   little more about SharePoint branding while looking a waffle-themed
>   demos there's going to be something for everyone!